# How use parameters of AdvertisingSetParameters in a bluetooth advertisement?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am making a Bluetooth Low Energy scanner and advertiser. I have already implemented the advertising using `AdvertiseSettings` but I want to change some parameters which are only available in `AdvertisingSetParameters`. There are methods like `onStartSuccess()` which only take in an object of the class `AdvertiseSettings` so I am facing a problem adding the parameters to the advertisement to it.

How should I pass the parameters in `AdvertisingSetParameters` to the advertisement?

The variable `advParameter` in the code below is something that I use as an input from the user to set the advertising interval.

**Code**

```
mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = 

BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

AdvertisingSetParameters parameters = new  AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
                                           .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_HIGH).build();

        switch (advParameter){
            case 0 :
                parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
                        .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_HIGH)
                        .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
                        .setConnectable(false)
                        .build();
                break;

            case 1 :
                parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
                        .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MEDIUM)
                        .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
                        .setConnectable(false)
                        .build();
                break;
            case 2 :
                parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
                        .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_LOW)
                        .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
                        .setConnectable(false)
                        .build();
                break;
            case 3 :
                parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
                        .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MIN)
                        .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
                        .setConnectable(false)
                        .build();
                break;
            case 4 :
                parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
                        .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MAX)
                        .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_HIGH)
                        .setConnectable(false)
                        .build();
                break;
        }

        AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
                .setConnectable(false)
                .build();

        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                .build();

        mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Advertising onStartFailure: " + errorCode);
                super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
            }
        };

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `AdvertisingSetParameters` are part of a new set of BLE APIs introduced in Android 8.0 requiring API level 26.  The `startAdvertising` method shown in the question is part of the older BLE APIs dating to Android 5.0 requiring only API level 21.  The `startAdvertising` method does not let you use `AdvertisingSetParameters`.

To apply `AdvertisingSetParameters`, simply use the newer `startAdvertisingSet` methods documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser#startAdvertisingSet(android.bluetooth.le.AdvertisingSetParameters,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData,%20android.bluetooth.le.PeriodicAdvertisingParameters,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData,%20int,%20int,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertisingSetCallback)).